# How can I create a Data Explorer Stream Analytics output using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-explorer, azure-stream-analytics

I successfully manually configured a Stream Analytics Job that outputs data into Data Explorer. However, I am unable to set up my infrastructure pipeline using ARM templates. All the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#outputdatasource) only describes the other types of output (e.g. ServiceBus).
I also tried exporting the template in the resource group, but this does not work for my Stream Analytics Job.

How can I configure this output using ARM templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many of such issues, you can use the following process:

1. Setup the desired configuration manually
2. Check https://resources.azure.com and find your resource
3. OR Export the resource using the [export template feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal)

In this case, resources.azure.com is sufficient.

If you look at the Data Explorer output resource, you will see the required ARM representation that you can use in your ARM template:

```json
"name": "xxxxxxx",
"type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/outputs",
"properties": {
"datasource": {
  "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases",
  "properties": {
    "cluster": "https://yyyyy.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
    "database": "mydatabase",
    "table": "mytable",
    "authenticationMode": "Msi"
  }
},
```

Comment: Is it possible that this datasource is not yet supported in the latest API version for streamingjobs? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) does not mention this datasource at all, with API versions up to "2021-10-01-preview".

Comment: @Habba should not be an issue. We have it working even with API version `2017-04-01-preview`